# JSDoc create and import type from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

I have a user object returned by some function in `user.model.js`

```
const user = {
    id: "ASwsd122Wqwe1",
    name: "sam",
    email: "sam.joe@yahoo.uk",
    createdDate : 1721323231123
}
```

In another file, I'm returning this

```
const user = getUser();
```

How do i create a type for user?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@typedef` to create custom types, where `@prop` refers `@property` are properties in your object.

syntax : `@typedef [<type>] <name>`

In you `user.model.js`,

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} user
 * @prop {string} id
 * @prop {string} name
 * @prop {string} email
 * @prop {number} createdDate
 */

// exports here
```

In another file, you can import the type like this

```
/** @typedef {import('./user.model.js').user} User */

/**@type {User} */
const user = getUser();
```

above globally defines the type

or

```
/**@type {import('./user.model.js').user} */
const user = getUser();
```